# Is it true that $A^{-1/2} xx^T A^{-1/2} \preceq (1 + x^T A^{-1} x) (A +xx^T)^{-1/2} xx^T (A + xx^T)^{-1/2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $A$ be a real, symmetric positive definite matrix and fix a vector $x$.

Is it true that
$$
A^{-1/2} xx^T A^{-1/2} \preceq (1 + x^T A^{-1} x) (A +xx^T)^{-1/2} xx^T (A + xx^T)^{-1/2}?
$$

It holds in one dimension, and also it is true that the trace of the LHS and the trace of RHS are equal, as can be verified using the rank-one update formula.

It is also true in the case $A = I$, and this can again be checked by the rank-one update formula.

Is the conjectured inequality above true or is there a simple counter example?

Comment: If $A \preceq B$ with $A,B$ positive semidefinite, then $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(B)$ implies that $A = B$. So probably, the statement has a counterexample

Comment: In fact, it suffices to find any matrix for which $(A + xx^T)^{-1/2}$ (or equivalently, $A + xx^T$) does not have $x$ as an eigenvector

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, it is of the form $uu^T \preceq vv^T$ which holds unless $u = c v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple counterexample: consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1\\1}.
$$